# Rails Active Record Omitting Where Clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Active Record query that sits inside of a gem. Database used is postgres.

```
Client.where(date:@date,client:@business_id)
```

The gem uses a get request to pull this data. When there are too many values in `@business_id`, the URI is too long. Gem does not have post requests.

**Workaround:**

The business problem is when all the `@business_id` get passed to the app. I could have an "all" button, that triggers all the `client` values to show. I would need to ignore the `client:@business_id` part of the query.

How could I construct the query so that when all of the `@business_id` need to be passed, it ignores the `client:@business_id` part of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chain the where clause and then conditionally include or exclude the @business_id part:

```
relation = Client.where(date:@date)
if your_conditional_is_true
  relation = relation.where(client:@business_id)
end
the_clients = relation.all
```

The reason this works is that where actually returns an ActiveRelation, not the results of executing the SQL. The SQL is not built and executed until you do something to work on the results of the relation.

Comment: What a great answer.. so useful for other stuff too